# Multiple Minimal Expression for a given logical function

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

My professor said that there can be logical functions with multiple minimal sum expressions. However, I am unable to find any such example. 
Can anyone please give an example of a logical function with multiple minimal expressions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework should have an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple minimal expressions occur when the solution requires some overlap in grouping or the grouping can be arraigned in a different way. Drawing a K-map is an easy way to visualize the groupings.

Overlap example (Condition \$ABC\$(all 1's) should be pair with \$A\bar{B}C\$ or \$AB\bar{C}\$):

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{K-map}&\text{Functions}\\
\begin{array}{r|cccc}
  &BC\\
  &00&01&11&10 \\
  \hline A\phantom{2}0&\color{blue}{}0&1&0&1 \\
  1&0&1&1&1 \\
\end{array}&\begin{align}\\
F & = \bar{B}C + B\bar{C} + \color{red}{AB} \\
& = \bar{B}C + B\bar{C} + \color{red}{AC} \\
\end{align}\\
\end{array}
$$

Grouping example (horizontal grouping, vertical grouping, plus Product-of-Sums):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{K-map}&\text{Functions}\\
\begin{array}{r|cccc}
  &CD\\
  &00&01&11&10 \\
  \hline AB\phantom{2}00&1&1&0&0 \\
  01&0&1&1&0 \\
  11&0&0&1&1 \\
  10&1&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}&\begin{align}\\
F_{SoP} & = \bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C} + \bar{A}BD + ABC + A\bar{B}\bar{D} \phantom{2}\color{blue}{\text{ // horizontal}}\\
& = \bar{B}\bar{C}\bar{D} + \bar{A}\bar{C}D + BCD + AC\bar{D} \phantom{2}\color{blue}{\text{  // vertical}} \\
\hline F_{PoS} & = (A+B+\bar{C}) (A+\bar{B}+D) (\bar{A}+\bar{B}+C) (\bar{A}+B+\bar{D}) \\
& = (\bar{B}+C+D)(\bar{A}+C+\bar{D})(B+\bar{C}+\bar{D})(A+\bar{C}+D) \\
\hline F_{SoP} & \equiv F_{PoS} \\
\end{align}\\
\end{array}
$$